# The shape does not fit the ggmap

Tags: shapefile, r, ggmap

I try to fit my shape to the google map.

```
require(rgdal)

in.dir <- getwd()

    sh <- readOGR(in.dir, layer = "Ytor", 
p4s = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15.80827777777778 +k=1 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs")


sh@proj4string 
sh2 <- spTransform(sh, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs"))

sh2@proj4string 

 sh2.df <- fortify(sh2)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

swe <- get_map(location = c(15.3, 63.63, 15.5, 63.68),  maptype = 'satellite')
ggmap(swe) + geom_polygon(aes(x = as.numeric(long), y = as.numeric(lat), group = group), data = df, color = "white", fill = "white", alpha = 0.1)
```

Finally I got the map as below[image]

The borders of the shape are not going as the ggmap borders. What did I wrong that the borders does not fit?

Comment: I once experienced problems with the projection of my data when using `readOGR` alongside with Google Maps data. Try to manually add the projection of layer "Ytor" (argument `p4s`) to `readOGR` and crosscheck the visualization afterwards.

Comment: Do I get it right? I should set the `p4s` argument in the function `readOGR`. How the argument should look like?

Comment: Just like the output of `proj4string`, I suppose. It's detailed in `?readOGR`. At least it's worth trying, helped me out back then.

Comment: @fdetsch I edited question. I added argument `p4s`in the `readOGR` function but it did not help? Did I make it right?

Comment: Yeah, it's correct. As I said, it was worth trying. Maybe somebody else knows what the problem is then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your projection string has no `towgs84` parameters.

Assuming your data is in `EPSG:3021 RT90 2.5 gon V`, it should be:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15.80827777777778 +k=1 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=414.1,41.3,603.1,-0.855,2.141,-7.023,0 +units=m +no_defs
```