# Using shp for ggmap in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am new to R and GIS.

I had a `shp` which I want to plot on google map.

The `shp`file is here: http://www.filedropper.com/exercisestanddata

First I do this:

```
ogrInfo(dsn=in.dir,layer="exercise_standdata")
```

The result is:

```
Source: "C:/", layer: "exercise_standdata"
Driver: ESRI Shapefile; number of rows: 65 
Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensions
Extent: (336536.2 6443835) - (338175.4 6445697)
CRS: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15.80827777777778 +k=1 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs  
LDID: 87 
Number of fields: 9 
        name type length typeName
1       AREA    0      9  Integer
2  PERIMETER    0      9  Integer
3    FORTYPE    0      9  Integer
4   TYPETEXT    4      9   String
5    StandID    0      4  Integer
6    landuse    0      4  Integer
7 SI_Species    4     10   String
8  Stand_age    0      4  Integer
9   Volu_pha    0      4  Integer
```

Than I read in the `shp` with the receipt that I recieved in the [The shape does not fit the ggmap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163273/the-shape-does-not-fit-the-ggmap)

```
sh <- readOGR(in.dir, layer = "exercise_standdata", p4s = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15.80827777777778 +k=1 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=414.1,41.3,603.1,-0.855,2.141,-7.023,0 +units=m +no_defs")
```

Then I do:

```
sh@proj4string # note projection details
sh2 <- spTransform(sh, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs"))
sh2@proj4string 

# Plotting with ggplot - first transform shapefile to data frame
library(ggplot2)
sh2.df <- fortify(sh2)

names(df)
# And plot
ggplot(data = sh2.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(colour = "grey20", fill = "white", size = 0.6)
```

However, now this does not work. It seems to work for the `y-axis` but not for `x-axis` that should be positive sth between 15-20.

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Can it be some problem with the `shp`?

Can someone explain the way how to transform the `shp` from any projection type to `longlat` format that can be used with `ggmap`?

```
After `readOGR` I got following warning
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "C:/Users/matliz/Documents/Heureka/Projects/PlanWise/Data/Ostad", layer: "exercise_standdata"
with 65 features
It has 9 fields
Warning message:
In readOGR(in.dir, layer = "exercise_standdata", p4s = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15.80827777777778 +k=1 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=414.1,41.3,603.1,-0.855,2.141,-7.023,0 +units=m +no_defs") :
  p4s= argument given as: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15.80827777777778 +k=1 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=414.1,41.3,603.1,-0.855,2.141,-7.023,0 +units=m +no_defs
 and read as: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15.80827777777778 +k=1 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs 
 read string overridden by given p4s= argument value
```